# I need help trying to set up a rectangular waveguide in HFSS,

Tags: waveguide

Task:
Setup a rectangular waveguide in HFSS using four perfect E boundaries on the side
faces of a box and waveports on the end faces of the box. Set up your dimensions so
that at the lowest frequency of your sweep, all modes are in cutoff. Set the highest
frequency of your sweep so that at least five modes will propagate.

I'm trying to do a frequency sweep from 1GHZ to 6GHZ. I am trying to find out what dimensions would allow for this.
Here is a link to my calculations in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ykntvv7yas.

I don't know how to interpret this data. The formula and values are set there.

Modes of Propagation:
[image: The modes up to 12]

Question:

I am trying to find out what length and width that I should use for the  waveguide (which has PEC walls and waveports) so that the first 5 modes of the rectangular wave guide are propagating at 6GHz and all modes are cut off at 1Ghz.

Comment: Can you edit the question and ask a specific question?

Answer (score 2):

For a typical rectangular waveguide (assuming a=2*b), the first 5 modes will be TE10, TE20, TE01, TE11, and TM11. The TEM00, TM01, and TM10 modes do not exist in this waveguide. So if we want the 6th mode to be cutoff at 6 GHz, we could solve for the TE (or TM) 21 modes. The cutoff frequency expression is given by:

$$f_{cmn} = \frac{c_0}{2\pi\sqrt{\epsilon_r}} \sqrt{\left(\frac{m \pi}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n \pi}{b}\right)^2}$$

where c0 is the speed of light and epsilon is the relative permitivity of the medium. So let's set f = 6 GHz, b = 2a, m = 2, and n = 1, and of course relative permittivity to 1, and solve for these dimensions. By my math I get b = 5.15 cm and a = 10.3 cm. Using the same expression, one can also determine that the cutoff for the lowest mode, TE10, is 1.455 GHz.

So a waveguide with a width of 10.3 cm and a height of 5.15 cm seems to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: thank you I will implement this into my design later, but is there a way to find out what modes are applicable in a given wave guide? And what determines the precedence of a mode of an other?

Comment: When I say the TEM00, TM01, and TM10 modes do not exist, this is a fundamental property of air core rectangular waveguides and comes analysis of the fields inside (i.e. it's something I took from a textbook and will change for each waveguide shape). If you loaded the rectangular waveguide partially with dielectric, you can in fact access the TM01 or TM10 mode if that's desirable.

Comment: As far as which mode comes first, it's simply which one has the lowest cutoff. Note that my notation calls the mode TEmn or TMnm, where m and n correspond to the equation I posted. If I had a "tall" waveguide where b = 2a, then my TE01 mode would come before my TE10 since b > a.